# Java: Access Location (GPS) on a Windows Tablet

Tags: java, windows, gps, location, jna

I have a tablet running Windows 8 with integrated GPS. I'm writing a Java fat client, that is supposed to access the device's position. I basically need a method to give me Latitude and Longitude preferably in the default WGS84 format. What is the best way to do that?

I know Java programming, but have no clue about Windows dll's, API and such.
After searching a bit on the web I figured one approach would be:

- using JNA to access Windows libraries
- the best *.dll seems to be LocationAPI.dll

Would this work? Is there a better way to achieve the desired goal?
Any pointers for a Windows API newbie, how to figure out what methods are there in LocationAPI and how can I transfer datatypes to Java?

Comment: The [Location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464636(v=vs.85).aspx) smells like COM, which makes it a bit more complicated than mapping vanilla C functions, but might be doable with Tobias Wolf's JNA+COM support (try to ping him on the [JNA user's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jna-users)).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll look into that. The issue is not top priority right now, but I'll come back here for sure ;)